# Datetime UTC/GMT time to local time "where I am"

Tags: c#, datetime

Let's say that I have this `DateTime(Mar/01/2015 09:55:52)`

I want to know if that time (I think this time is from Germany, anyways, I'm living in Brazil and the difference between us is 4hours).

So basically:

`DateTime` I have: `Mar/01/2015 09:55:52`

`DateTime.Now` That representes "where I am": `Mar/01/2015 05:55:52`

I want to make this `parse` to tell me, for example, if that "DateTime that I have" is 1 minutes after at least and 10 minuts later at maximum from the "DateTime where I am".

Comment: So let me get this clear. if I had time "x", you want the program to return true if "it's between 1 and 10 minutes later" and false otherwise.

Comment: yes Don.. but there are differents time, from differents zones... that's the problem.

Comment: There's not enough information from what you posted. You must include something to indicate the timezone or UTC offset. You can't just guess that the original is from Germany.

Comment: Joel, as I said, I know that there are 4 hours of diff...  and I'm pretty sure that the time is from germany.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on `.net 4.5` - you can use the `TimeZoneInfo` class, it has a `ConvertTime` method that lets you pass in a datetime and a timezone

[TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime Method (DateTime, TimeZoneInfo)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb382835%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

you can use it like:

```
DateTime dateTimeIhave = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(dateTheyGave, theirTimeZone, yourTimeZone);

if (dateTimeIhave > DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
            && dateTimeIhave < DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(10))
{
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//pseudocode
//DateTime that represents where you're at = dnow;
//DateTime that you have = dhave;

//convert dnow and dhave to seconds using this algorithm:
//convert the time into a string and get the data using a parser.
//int seconds = current seconds;
//seconds += minutes * 60;
//seconds += hours * 60 * 60;
```

Then find out if both times are between 60 seconds and 600 seconds from each other.